# Keep asking until the correct value is given with 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm currently working on a small project given by an edX course. I stuck with one thing, taking values from users and storing them in a 2d array. However, the values should be in a range, and so I need to re-prompt the same thing, which is the necessary conditions fulfilled.

I've found a solution by myself, but I don't know if its a common practice or there is a better way to do it.

Let me explain;

So I have this array like this:

`int[][] userCoordinates = new int[5][2];`

I want to fill this array with the user's coordinate information, but the coordinates should be between 0 to 9.

I did something like this;

```
int coordinateValueX = 0, coordinateValueY = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < userCoordinates.length; i++) {

 // X - Value

 for (int j = 0; j <= 0; j++) {
  System.out.print("Enter X coordinate for your " + (i + 1) + ". ship:");
  coordinateValueX = input.nextInt();

  if (gridCheck(coordinateValueX)) {
   j--;
  }
 }

 // Y - Value

 for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {
  System.out.print("Enter Y coordinate for your " + (i + 1) + ". ship:");
  coordinateValueY = input.nextInt();

  if (gridCheck(coordinateValueY)) {
   j--;
  }
 }
}
```

And the gridCheck method is this:

```
public static boolean gridCheck(int coordinateValue) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (coordinateValue > 9 || coordinateValue < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid grid, please give your coordinate again.");
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I tried using while-continue, but the problem with that is when the user gives a wrong Y value, it asks the x value all over again because it iterates to the next loop.

Open for the suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with arrays, it’s all about input.

Create a method that asks for a value from the user and doesn’t return until it gets a value within a certain range, something like:

```
private int askForInt(Scanner scanner, String coordName, int max) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Give your " + coordName + " coordinate: ");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine(); // clear new line from buffer
        if (i >= 0 && i <= max) {
            return i;
        }
        System.err.println("Please enter a number between 0 and " + max);
    }
}
```

Now your main code becomes clean and simple. No need to decrement loop variables (modifying loop variables inside a loop is generally to be avoided - it’s confusing when reading the code), and you can focus on the main logic of the loop without the annoyance of bad user input.

Answer (score 0):

Aah, that's really great. You also taught me that I can pass the scanner to methods.  From your post, I did something like this if I understood correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] userCoordinates = new int[5][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < userCoordinates.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < userCoordinates[0].length; j++) {
            if(j == 0)
                userCoordinates[i][j] = validateCoordinate(scanner, "x");
                        if(j == 1)
                            userCoordinates[i][j] = validateCoordinate(scanner, "y");
        }
    }
```

I think I can do this gridCheck business inside the valideCoordinate but I dont know if it decreases the readability.

```
public static boolean gridCheck(int coordinateValue) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (coordinateValue > 9 || coordinateValue < 0) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Add xory option because I want to prompt if its x or y.

```
public static int validateCoordinate(Scanner scanner, String xory){

    while(true){
        if(xory.equals("x")){
        System.out.print("Give your X coordinate: ");
        }else if (xory.equals("y")){
            System.out.print("Give your Y coordinate: ");
        }

        int coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
        if(!gridCheck(coordinate)){
            return coordinate;
        }else{
            System.err.println("Please give a valid coordinate.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can further simplify the prompt. See my updated answer. And sure, use your gridCheck method within the input getting method. Also, this “answer” should have been a comment on my answer, since that’s its purpose.

Comment: Thanks for holding my hand.  For the next time, I'll comment on people's comment.